# Django: How can I use get_model in my use case to correctly import a class and avoid conflicts

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model with a get_form method.

```
# models.py

from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager
from breathingactivities.forms import ParentRecordForm, ChildRecordForm


class ParentRecord(models.Model):
    ....
    objects = InheritanceManager()

    def get_fields(self, exclude=('user')):
        fields = self._meta.fields
        return [(f.verbose_name, f.value_to_string(self)) for f in fields if not exclude.__contains__(f.name)]

    @classmethod
    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return ParentRecordForm

class ChildRecord(ParentRecord):
    ....
    duration = DurationField(
    _('Duration'),
    help_text=_('placeholder'))

    @classmethod
    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ChildRecordForm
```

I have a view that uses this get_form method to determine to correct form for a given object.

```
# views.py

class ParentRecordUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = ParentRecord
    form_class = ParentRecordForm
    template_name = 'parentrecords/create.html'

    def get_object(self, **kwargs):
        return ParentRecord.objects.get_subclass(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

    def get_form_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.model.objects.get_subclass(slug=self.kwargs['slug']).get_form()
        return form_class

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ParentRecordUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

I am using InheritanceManager from django-model-utils so I get a clean API to subclasses when I query a parent class - that is the get_subclass() stuff, and this is why my view works with ParentRecord.

All this works good. I see via console that indeed form_class is the form class I'd expect, for example, ChildRecordForm when the instance is of ChildRecord.

In my forms.py, I can't just import models.ParentRecord and models.ChildRecord, as I import those forms in my models.py, and thus an error is raised that Django can't import these models. I presume because of circular imports.

So, I try this instead:

```
# forms.py

from django.db.models import get_model

class ParentRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super (ParentRecordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = get_model('model', 'ParentRecord')
        exclude = ('user')

class ChildRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super (ChildRecordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = get_model('model', 'ParentRecord')
        exclude = ('user')
```

However, model for these forms always returns None.

I I go and pass ChildRecordForm some totally unrelated model that I can import from a different app in my project, for example:

```
# forms.py

from another_app import AnotherModel

class ChildRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super (ChildRecordForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = AnotherModel
        exclude = ('user')
```

Then it works, meaning, The form returns the fields of AnotherModel.

So, I can't work out why get_model() works for me in shell, but not in a form class when I use it to declare a value for a model.

Comment: Just as a matter of style, the first argument to a `classmethod` is usually named `cls`, rather than `self`.

Comment: Ok great, wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess on `get_model()` is that running it at the class-definition level can give incorrect results, since it will get evaulated as Django is populating all the models in it's AppCache. My quick reading of the `django.db.models.loading` module doesn't seem to show that issue, but one thing to try is to run `get_model()` inside a *view* and print out the results to see if it is what you think it should be, since by that time the `AppCache` should be fully loaded.

But - as a workaround to get around the original circular import (so you don't have to use get_model anyway) is to not do the form imports at the module level - you can stick them in the classmethod instead:

```
class ParentRecord(models.Model):
    @classmethod
    def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from yourapp.forms import BreathingActivityRecordForm
        return BreathingActivityRecordForm
```

This way, the import will only be evaulated when you actually call `.get_form()`, and there shouldn't be any circular dependencies at module loading tme.

Comment: I think this is correct. I've been using get_model very extensively and have been stung by it returning None because I'm interpreting a module before the app cache is loaded.

Comment: When you import your modules in a method or function like you do there, each time the function is called the import as to be evaluated. Isn't it time cunsuming ?

Comment: The `import` statement has to be evaluated, but the module itself isn't reloaded once it's in `sys.modules`. The overhead is negligible, a fraction of a millisecond for me. https://gist.github.com/3193380

Comment: Spooky, this was EXACTLY my issue, even down to using InheritanceManager!