# get_model() vs from .models import somemodelname

Tags: django, django-models

What is/are the best practices to use get_model() and when should it be imported ?

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/

Comment: You usually use `get_model()` when you need to dynamically get a model class. For example, you have an app which has dynamically built serializers and you set their `Meta.model` to the class you just got with `get_model()` . The other option is the default way to import models.

Answer (score 2):

You usually use `get_model()` when you need to dynamically get a model class.

A practical example: when writing a `RunPython` operation for a migration, you get the app registry as one of the args, and you use `apps.get_model('TheModel')` to import  historical models.

Another example: you have an app which has dynamically built serializers and you set their `Meta.model` to the class you just got with `get_model()` .

Yet another example is importing models in `AppConfig.ready()` with `self.get_model()`.

An important thing to remember, if you are using `AppConfig.get_model()` or `apps.get_models()`, that they can be used only once the application registry is fully populated.

The other option (`from .models import TheModel`) is just the default way to import models anywhere in your code.

These are just examples though, there are many other possible scenarios.

Comment: [You cannot import models in modules that define application configuration classes, but you can use get_model() to access a model class by name, like this:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready)

So models cannot be imported in that case?

Answer (score -1):

I Prefer, use .models import, cause is a simple way to get the Model Object.
But if you works with metaclasses, maybe the [get_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model), would be the best option.

```
def get_model(self, app_label, model_name=None):
        """
        Returns the model matching the given app_label and model_name.

        As a shortcut, this function also accepts a single argument in the
        form <app_label>.<model_name>.

        model_name is case-insensitive.

        Raises LookupError if no application exists with this label, or no
        model exists with this name in the application. Raises ValueError if
        called with a single argument that doesn't contain exactly one dot.
        """
        self.check_models_ready()
        if model_name is None:
            app_label, model_name = app_label.split('.')
        return self.get_app_config(app_label).get_model(model_name.lower())
```

Maybe this [SO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804044/django-db-models-loading-get-model-vs-importing), can help too.

Comment: This does not answer his question, is not about "simpler way", is about good practices and when using it.

Comment: We have two questions:
What is/are the best practices to use get_model() AND WHEN should it be imported ?
and really the point it is not a good practice, only when using.
and if you think my answer was not helpful, it has every right to give the downvote.
and I'm sorry for making you waste your time reading it